# How to speed up nested for loops in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, internet-explorer, canvas

I want to filter an image with a predefined filter mask in JavaScript using the HTML5 Canvas Element.

I found a solution which works fine:

```js
//define source canvas
var srccanv = document.getElementById("src_canvas");
var ctx = srccanv.getContext("2d");
var w = srccanv.width;
var h = srccanv.height;

//just draw something into the canvas
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="gray";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray";
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.stroke();

//define destination canvas
var dstcanv = document.getElementById("dst_canvas");
var dctx = dstcanv.getContext("2d");
var dstImageData = dctx.getImageData(0,0,dstcanv.width,dstcanv.height);
var dst = dstImageData.data;


//filtermask
var filtermask = [-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1];


var side = Math.round(Math.sqrt(filtermask.length));
var halfSide = Math.floor(side/2);
var srcImageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
var src = srcImageData.data;
var sw = w;
var sh = h;

console.time('convolution');
// go through the destination image pixels
for (var y=1; y<h-1; y++) {
   for (var x=1; x<w-1; x++) {
   
     var sy = y;
     var sx = x;
     var dstOff = (y*w+x)*4;

     // calculate the weighed sum of the source image pixels that
     // fall under the convolution matrix    
     var r=0, g=0, b=0, a=0;
     for (var cy=0; cy<side; cy++) {
        for (var cx=0; cx<side; cx++) {
           
           var scy = sy + cy - halfSide;
           var scx = sx + cx - halfSide;
           if (scy >= 0 && scy < sh && scx >= 0 && scx < sw) {
              var srcOff = (scy*sw+scx)*4;
              var wt = filtermask[cy*side+cx];
              r += src[srcOff] * wt;
              g += src[srcOff+1] * wt;
              b += src[srcOff+2] * wt;
              a += src[srcOff+3];
           }
         }
      } 
       
       
      dst[dstOff] = r;
      dst[dstOff+1] = g;
      dst[dstOff+2] = b;
      dst[dstOff+3] = 255;
       
  }
 }
console.timeEnd('convolution');


dctx.putImageData(dstImageData,0,0);
```

```html
<canvas id="src_canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="dst_canvas"></canvas>
```

or see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w0fuxt64/20/

But... I found out that the performance in IE11 is very bad. I tested my code with latest versions of firefox (38.5.2 ESR) and Chrome (47.0) and I got some results around 10-20ms for the filtering of an 300px by 150px canvas. (See time in developer console of your browser)

Testing with IE gave me results around 280ms! which is way too long to be useful for my purposes. Does anybody have any ideas how to dramatically improve this code for IE.

Thanks in advance

Beni

Comment: If I correctly read your question, the operation you time is totally unrelated to the canvas, it's mostly loops and array access, right ? If that's the case, you should probably change the title and tags.

Comment: Thanks, yes you're probably right. But I'm not sure if it's totally unreleated to the canvas, because I work with an Uint8ClampedArray received from a canvas. So I changed the title.

Comment: Right. It would be interesting to compare with performances on regular arrays (I'm personally IE-free so I won't help you)